# Findfactorial was not found in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

Every time I run my Qt program, it gives the following error:

> Findfactorial was not found in this scope

Could someone suggest why? I have the function in my `mainwindow.cpp`

```
int findFactorial(int x){
    if(x == 1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x*findFactorial(x-1);
    }
}
```

`mainwindow.h` :

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    bool ok = false;
    int findFactorial(int x);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

    void on_clear_button_clicked();

    void on_sqr_button_clicked();

    void on_exp_two_button_clicked();

    void on_pi_button_clicked();

    void on_ceil_button_clicked();

    void on_factorial_button_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Comment: You probably wrote `Findfactorial` somewhere, but the function is called `findFactorial` (C++ is case sensitive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly say to which scope/namespace does this function belongs using *scope resolution operator*.

```
int MainWindow::findFactorial(int x){
    if(x == 1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x*findFactorial(x-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you didnt know that :)

Comment: Glad it helped :-) You can read more about namespaces [here(click)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).